# Is Boost::asio officially supported on ios & android?

Tags: android, ios, boost, boost-asio

Is Boost::asio officially supported on ios & android ?

I am using asio for networking on ios & android. It works all fine, but I don't want to get into trouble after my app is released & one fine day with one ios/android OS update asio stops working.

Hence, wish to check:- Is Boost::asio officially supported on ios & android ?

Comment: Boost is not officially supported on iOS and Android, but there are some forks out there:

https://www.crystax.net/android/ndk | 

https://github.com/moritz-wundke/Boost-for-Android (maybe dead) | 

https://github.com/danoli3/ofxiOSBoost (maybe dead)

Comment: @Ray. This is really sad. ehh ! It works so well for my networking app. I am able to build it for ios & android as well from source. I was hoping that it will get included in C++ 17 based on the networking proposal as well. http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0112r1.html  Is there a chance that its functionality might break in future versions of ios/android ?

Comment: Huh. @NelsonP you should ask that with Google/Apple. As long as you build your own binaries from source, you're "safe"; (it'll only break if Google/Apple breaks you and they might be able to provide support then?) Yes ASIO is considered for C++17. What's the alternative? You writing everything in Java? Inventing the wheel? I get the feeling you're looking for "that extra checkmark" on your corporate "support guarantees" spreadsheet. That's only relevant if you have viable alternatives.

Comment: @RayHamel: moritz-wundke's Boost-for-Android hasn't seen much love for some time now, it's mostly because of how many (Boost, NDKs, G++s) combinations it's trying to support (to the point when it's overwhelming). I'm using it [this](https://github.com/inetic/Boost-for-Android/tree/android_r12-boost_1_58_0) branch (mostly Asio and Program Options) and don't have any issues.

Comment: @sehe Other options are to write native back-ends in java & objective-c which calls for their own complications. But I really-really want to stick with asio. I've used it for sometime & it is very powerful. You can call it the "extra checkmark". Yes :) But I am worried that any update of ios/android might break asio's functionality & bring my app down which promarilly depends on network APIs.      And yesss !! I am building my boost binaries from source. Does that guarantee me safety ?

Comment: It guarantees you control. Asio depends on platform independent API's (mostly POSIX/BSD sockets). Why would Android or iOS break them? All you can predict is toolchain churn (when new compilers emit new warnings etc.)